# HttpsURLConnection gets SSLHandshakeException on alternate invocations

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I am getting this exception on every other invocation of my Java program:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I am running Java 1.5.0_15 on an OpenSuSE Linux machine. I have downloaded the root certificates from the VeriSign web site and imported them using keytool.

The code does nothing unusual - just send a couple of parameters and read the response. The code is at the end of this post.

It does look like I don't have a required certificate installed, but I really don't get why I'm seeing this problem on every second invocation!?

I have used -Djavax.net.debug=ssl and have the output from both the working invocation and the failed invocation. The first few hundred lines of output are the same and then I get this output from the failed invocation:

```
***
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
    sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
    unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
    sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
...

%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
```

The full output generated as a result of the -Djavax.net.debug=ssl property is too much to include in this post.

Here is the test program I am using:

```
<imports go here>
public class HttpPoster
{
    public static final String s_target = "https://<url goes here>";
    private static final String s_parameters = "a=100&b=200";

    public void runTest()
    {
        HttpURLConnection connection = createHttpConnection(s_target);

        String response = null;
        int     statusCode = -1;
        String responseMessage = null;

        try
        {
            response = sendRequest(connection, s_parameters);
            statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            responseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            System.out.println("Response = " +response);
            System.out.println("Status Code = " +statusCode);
            System.out.println("Response Message = " +responseMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.disconnect();
                connection = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private String sendRequest(HttpURLConnection connection, String parameters)
    {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        try
        {
            // Calling getOutputStream() does an implicit connect()
            OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            outputWriter.write(parameters);
            outputWriter.flush();

            // Get the response
            String line = null;

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            if (outputWriter != null) {
                outputWriter.close();
            }

            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }

    private HttpURLConnection createHttpConnection(String url)
    {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try
        {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url)).openConnection();

            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setReadTimeout(15000);

            setHostNameVerifier(connection);

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException murlException)
        {
            murlException.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ioException)
        {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }

        return connection;
    }

    private void setHostNameVerifier(HttpURLConnection c)
    {
        HostnameVerifier hv = null;

        if (c instanceof HttpsURLConnection)
        {
            hv = new HostnameVerifier()
            {
                public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session)
                {
                    // Ignore the domain mismatch
                    return true;
                }
             };

            ((HttpsURLConnection)c).setHostnameVerifier(hv);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            new HttpPoster().runTest();
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: A couple of quick points: (a) it's time to upgrade your JRE. Java 6 itself is soon to be abandoned and (b) leave the host name verifier alone: what you're doing disables host name verification, but that's an essential part of what makes an HTTPS connection secure. Is it your own server? Do you always get the same certificate from that server? It might help to delete the Verisign CA certs that are no longer valid from your trust store.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. Upgrading the JRE is not an option in the short term as we have hundreds of Linux instances in the cloud. Also, the HostNameVerifier is because the particular code I grabbed this example from is required to do that because the third party service it is connecting to (using different customer-specific URLs) requires it (their bad).

Comment: If you're not actually verifying the host name in the certificate, you might as well trust any certificate. I'm not going to copy and paste one of the numerous examples of trustmanagers that trust anything (the kind of answers I usually downvote), but there are examples around... ([EOL notification for Java 5 was 4 years ago, btw](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html)).